# How to send variables from python to shell and then to hive?

Tags: python, shell, hive

I am trying to run some hive code using Shell script. But I need to do some array manipulation before calling the beeline. I tried doing the array manipulation in shell but faced issues. Now the other option is to use python to do the array manipulation and then pass my variables to shell script which will then in turn pass them to hive. Is is a POC I am trying to do to see if it is possible.

It will be helpful if there is a way to capture the table_name var value in shell script.

Python Code:

```py
from subprocess import Popen
table_name='abcd'
Process=Popen(['/users/${whoami}/username/run.sh',str(table_name)],shell=True)
```

Shell Script : (run.sh)

```
process_name=run_smaple
log_path=/users/$(whoami)/username
script_path=/users/$(whoami)/username
schema_name=dev_env
suffix=$(date +'%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S')
log_file=${log_path}/${process_name}_${suffix}.log
beeline_cont="jdbc:hive2...... "

beeline -u ${beeline_cont} \
        --hiveconf hive.execution.engine=mr \
        --hiveconf mapred.job.queuename=ent\
        --hivevar script=${script} \
        --hivevar schema_name=${schema_name} \
        --hivevar table_name=${table_name} \
        -f ${script_path}/sample.hql &>> $log_file
```

Hive (sample.hql)

```
select count(*) from ${schema_name}.${table_name};
```

cannot recognize input near 'dev_env' '.' '' in table name (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: You can set it in the `env` parameter to the `Popen` call, but this setup seems very convoluted... why don't you do the run.sh logic in Python since you're already there..?

Comment: @thebjorn, you are right, but how do I execute a file using python. I would appreciate that information. I have an HQL and I wan't to execute it using python. All the examples I see have only one query being executed using python. I want to execute a file. (.hql)

Comment: Check the docs for `subprocess.run(..)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks. I thought about the first comment. Executing Hive query directly using python made more sense. I am using that now.